# es6 function declaration in React class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Whats the difference between functions declared with const and functions declared without let or const and a function declared otherwise in an ES6 class?

```
class App extends Component {

    submitFood = () =>{
        // some code
    }
```

Why does the above work OK but the declaration below give an error:

```
class App extends Component {

    const submitFood = () =>{
        // some code
        }
```

Comment: Because they are `member functions` or `methods` and are part of the `Class` you declare.

Comment: It's not always clear how to answer questions that ask "why is this not valid syntax". It's not valid syntax because the language simply doesn't allow it. Or do you want to know the reason behind the decision to not allow this syntax? In that case you have to talk to the people who made that decision.

Comment: They're both invalid ES6, so I'd say it's not much difference.

Answer (score 5):

First of all: None of the examples you provided is valid ES6. [The grammar rules for ES6 classes](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-class-definitions) only allow *methods definitions* inside the class body. I.e.

```
class MyClass {
  method1() {}
  method2() {}
}
```

The first example however is making use of the [**class fields proposal**](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields). This proposal extends the existing grammar to allow the definition of properties of the form

```
class MyClass {
  someProperty = value;
}
```

These assignments are not evaluated at class definition time but at instantiation time. It's syntactic sugar for assigning properties in the constructor:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.someProperty = value;
  }
}
```

---

Your second example is simply invalid syntax because there are no grammar rules that allow putting `let` or `const` before the class field.

Keep in mind that class fields are *not* variable declarations or variable assignments.

Answer (score -3):

`const submitFood = () =>{
        // some code
        }`

Is the creation of function `(submitFood=() {})` and the creation of a variable so usual rules in variable hosting blocked `let` and `const`.
so fail since `submitFood()` is not defined. (It will throw a  ReferenceError).